# Serialize a list of numpy arrays and read back/deserialize into Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, serialization, pyarrow

Consider a list of numpy arrays:

```
arr = [np.linspace(a1,a2,11) for a1,a2 in [(1,10),(20,30)]]
nparr = np.array(arr)
```

I would like to serialize this to transmit to a Javascript REST client. The preferred approach is

- Efficiently serialize into a binary-safe format and bake that into a Base64 encoded field in a JSON object
- Transmit the JSON object over http
- Receive the JSON object into javascript listener.
- Base64 decode the field and deserialize into binary array using an efficient javascript deserialization library

I have done an initial investigation into *apache arrow* that has support in both languages.

Note: I tried the following:

- convert to two dimensional *numpy* array
- convert to *pyarrow*

Following happened

```
pyarr = pya.array(nparr)


ArrowInvalid                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-68eb3e5f578f> in <module>
----> 1 pyarr = pya.array(nparr)

ArrowInvalid: only handle 1-dimensional arrays
```

So *pyarrow* seems pretty limited in terms of the structures of the data it can serialize.  I also am looking into the *apache parquet* format : but that seems to require actually writing to disk/filesystem?

Working code for those two technologies or possibly a different library/approach would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow is capable of serializing list of arrays of float. But I think it needs a little help if the list is multi dimension numpy array:

```
pa.array(
    arr.tolist(),
    pa.list_(pa.float64())
)
```

But given your use case, since all arrays have got the same length, I'd recomment using a `Table` instead an `Array`

```
schema = pa.schema(
        [
            pa.field(str(i), pa.float64())
            for i in range(len(nparr))
        ]
        
    )

table = pa.Table.from_arrays(
    nparr,
    schema=schema
)
```